# PHP get date from string

Tags: php, date, date-formatting

I'm from mail source I get dates like: **Mon, 22 Jul 2013 09:08:50 +0200**
I must get from this dates date: `2013-07-22`.
I try this

```
$date = "Mon, 22 Jul 2013 09:08:50 +0200";
date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date))
```

What I do wrong ?

Comment: You didn't even `echo` / `print` it out. Read the manual.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, except the syntax: http://codepad.org/d2Xklppb

Comment: add `;` after date() and `echo` before date() for start :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to echo the resulting value. Also, note that the output will be affected by the time zone on the machine running the PHP script.

Comment: *affected by timezone*

Answer (score 2):

Use like this

```
      $date = "Mon, 22 Jul 2013 09:08:50 +0200";
      echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Yeah! strtotime() is a great way and commonly used method to convert a date from string to a certain format the way you need it to be.